# How to check if member has role discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a "warn" command and I want to check if member has role.
My code:

```
async def пред(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    р.Персонал=discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.id == '701381413215141948', ctx.message.server.roles)
    if р.Персонал not in member.roles:
        print("You don't have role")
        return
    else:
        print('Success')
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Att
ributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Comment: Replace `server` with `guild`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as `InsertChessyLine` it should be `ctx.guild.roles` instead of `ctx.message.server.roles`

```
async def пред(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    р.Персонал=discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.id == '701381413215141948', ctx.guild.roles)
    if р.Персонал not in member.roles:
        print("You don't have role")
        return
    else:
        print('Success')
```